# Why onScan function is getting called two times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

Below function is deployed on aws lamdba however I am getting every record two times because onScan function gets called two times in a single request.
When I checked with AWS CLI corresponding dynamoDB table there are only two records present.

Copied the code of "onScan" function from aws documentation website.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var commons = require("../../Utils/common_utils");
AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require("bluebird"));
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.listProduct = (event, context, callback) => {
  var items = [];
  var params = {
    TableName: process.env.PRODUCT_TABLE
  };
  docClient
    .scan(params, onScan)
    .promise()
    .then(res => {
      callback(null, {
        headers: commons.getCorsHeader(),
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "Success",
          products: items
        })
      });
    });

  function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(
        "Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:",
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
      );
    } else {
      items = items.concat(data.Items);
      if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
        console.log("Scanning for more...");
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
        docClient.scan(params, onScan);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**This is My Output:**

```
{
        "message": "Success",
        "products": [
            {
                "price": "1",
                "product_name": "Iteraconazole Tab",
                "product_id": "Iteraconazole Tab1"
            },
            {
                "price": "200",
                "product_name": "Luliconazole",
                "product_id": "Luliconazole200"
            },
            {
                "price": "1",
                "product_name": "Iteraconazole Tab",
                "product_id": "Iteraconazole Tab1"
            },
            {
                "price": "200",
                "product_name": "Luliconazole",
                "product_id": "Luliconazole200"
            }
        ]
    }
```

the records in the products is only two. the expected output should be two records but getting 4.